# AdminLTE sidebar-collapse set not hidden when screen is smaller (i.e. smartphone)

Tags: css, adminlte

I have got a sidebar-collapse that with the screen is smaller become hidden.
I would like to keep it visible.
How to do?

[image: Sidebar visible]
[image: Sidebar not visible, I would like to keep it visible]

Regards